# Disable shadow in RatingBar

Tags: android, user-interface, ratingbar

I use RatingBar in my application. I'd like to remove shadows (they're underlined on screenshot), but I don't know how to do it.

My style:

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Could you tell me how to remove shadows?

[image: Shadow in RatingBar]

Comment: try setting elevation to 0dp in your theme

Comment: I've tried. It doesn't work

Comment: Did you find a solution? Facing the same issue here too!

Answer (score 7):

A bit late but if you're using API 21+, you can set the secondary progress tint to be transparent:

```
android:secondaryProgressTint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue too. I figured it out. The drawable at 1 index changes that shadow color. You can set it to the much lighter color of your actual filled star color.

```
RatingBar ratingBar = footer.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
        stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#b0b0b0"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#fff9ee"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);// This line changes the color of the shadow under the stars
        stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FEBE55"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        ratingBar.setProgressDrawable(stars);
```